# Can I access a functions return value twice without storing it in a variable or calling the function again?

Tags: c

Function `id_data_valid(data)` may return 0, or a given error code (-1, 1, -2, 2,..., N). Is there a way in C to use the function's return value, without defining a new  variable, or calling the function twice, as the examples below show?

```
/* Store return value */
int response = id_data_valid(data);
if (response != 0) {
    return response;
}

/* Double function call */
if (id_data_valid(data) != 0) {
    return id_data_valid(data);
}
```

Comment: No, and do not worry about defining new variables. The compiler will optimize the code. The “Store return value” example above would likely result in the compiler testing the response in the register the function returned it in, without moving it to any other place, and, if it returns, it would just do its normal return without needing to move the value, since it is already in the correct place to be returned. In other words, the code likely compiles to a test and a branch. The code in C is just an expression of the end result, not directions to produce certain assembly instructions.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to fix?

Comment: Why is defining a new variable a problem?

Comment: I smell an XY-problem here. What is the actual problem? Neither of your approaches is bad in any way, provided that the function does not have side effects. If it has side effects, use the variable approach.

Comment: Just curious: What happens if the return value is 0?

Comment: @SouravGhosh 7 eats 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is completely impossible. If you want to use the return value from a function twice, you either have to store it in a variable or call the function again.

In Bash, there is a feature which kind of is what you want. There, the *latest* exit code (return value) is stored in a builtin global variable called `$?`, but this feature does not exist in C, and I cannot really see the point either in a language like C. A similar snippet in Bash could look like this:

```
if ! my_command; then
    exit "$?"
fi
```

But Bash is a completely different language. I cannot see how such a feature would be good in C.

I would go for the first option with declaring a new variable. The second option is also fine *provided* that the function has no side effects.

> without defining a new variable

Technically, this is possible to fulfill by reusing an old variable, but that is not a good solution. Don't do it.

One thing you can do that prevents future use of the variable is to put everything in a scope. This is the C equivalent of the C++ code Bathsheba showed in another answer.

```
{ // Extra brace
int response = id_data_valid(data);
if (response != 0) {
    return response;
}}

// Now response has gone out of scope, so this would be an error
if(response == 0) {
```

In one way, this is a good thing to do, because it encapsulates temporary variables. But on the other hand, if you really need this construct, it is a very good sign that you instead should rethink your design.

Comment: In the shell, `$?` is a 'global variable' and global variables are bad.  C shouldn't (and doesn't) have an analogous mechanism.

Comment: I don't see how the Bash stuff is relevant here - why mention something from another language which doesn't apply to C?

Comment: @4386427 I just thought it was a good idea to show an example of where it is actually possible.

Comment: @Broman hmm... then we could make examples from all kind of languages in C answers - not sure I would like that.

Comment: @4386427 I did it because it's simply not possible at all in C. How would I do an example in C in this case?

Comment: @Broman well, in my mind it would be sufficient to state that it's not possible in C - end of story. OP is asking about C so no reason to tell about Bash, Perl, java, python,.... To me it just makes the answer confusing but ... well, never mind

Comment: @4386427 I think it added to the answer in this particular case. If you disagree, feel free to down vote.

Comment: @4386427 Hehe. Furthermore, I think the benefits both of including and excluding that snippet is so minor that it's not worth further discussion. :)

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way in C to use the function's return value, without defining a new variable, or calling the function twice[...]?

Yes, with `switch`

```
switch (id_data_valid(data)) {
    default: return 0;
    case 1: /* ... */ return 1;
    case -1: /* ... */ return -1;
    case 2: /* ... */ return 2;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @4386427: I changed the code a little bit. Maybe better now?